# Conditional classname in react based on a function return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React project, I'm trying to set different icons for each item based on their existence in an array which I get from local storage.

**table.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import isMovieInFavorites from './favorites';

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        movies: [],
        //other state vars
    }
  }

  //some other codes
  render(){
      return (
        <div className="table-container">
          <table>
            {this.state.movies.map((row) => (
              <tr key={row.id}>
                <td>{row.title}</td>
                <td className="icon"><i className={(isMovieInFavorites(row.id) ? "fas" : "far") + " fa-star"}></i></td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </table>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to change classname between `fas` and `far` based on `isMovieInFavorites(id)` from

**favorites.js**

```
function isMovieInFavorites(id){
  let movieArray = localStorage.getItem('faveMovieList') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('faveMovieList')) : [];
  movieArray.forEach((movie)=>{
    if(movie.id === id)
      return true;
  });
  return false;
}
```

I guess I'm doing fine with this part:

```
{(isMovieInFavorites(row.id) ? "fas" : "far") + " fa-star"}
```

Cause the condition works well if I check the results in `console.log` (inside `favorites.js`). Also if I do something like `{(row.id == 10 ? "fas" : "far") + " fa-star"}`, it works fine. But calling the function and checking the result somehow doesn't work and always will apply class `far` even the result is `true`.

What am I missing here? Is it wrong to call a function in this situation?

export default isMovieInFavorites;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here problem is with your function, forEach doesn't return anything out of callback, so the function will always return `false`

```
function isMovieInFavorites(id){
  let movieArray = localStorage.getItem('faveMovieList') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('faveMovieList')) : [];
  movieArray.forEach((movie)=>{
    if(movie.id === id)
      return true;
  });
  return false;
}
```

You need to use `some` or simple `for` loop instead

```
function isMovieInFavorites(id){
  let movieArray = localStorage.getItem('faveMovieList') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('faveMovieList')) : [];
  return movieArray.some(movie => movie.id === id)
}
```

Comment: Use array.some instead of the forEach. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some